# Why is the IFS formula not working in a recursive LAMBDA function in Excel?

Tags: excel, recursion, lambda

**Excel "IFS" does not work in a recursive LAMBDA function.**

Would anyone know why the "IFS" formula does not work in a recursive LAMBDA function?

For example:
`=LAMBDA(y,x,IF(x=0, y, RecurseSubtract((y-1), (x-1))))`
works fine.  However if it was modified to use "IFS":
`=LAMBDA(y,x,IFS(x=0, y, TRUE, RecurseSubtract((y-1), (x-1))))`
then it no longer works.

I am using a much more complicated recursive LAMBDA function but I was able to track the problem down to the "IFS" formula.  Also I tested the "IFS" formula in a non-recursive LAMBDA function and it works fine.

Comment: Unlike `IF`, `IFS` evaluates all conditions - whether `TRUE` or not - prior to passing the final result. So I presume that your `IFS` version is looping endlessly. Perhaps [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/ifs-evaluates-all-elements/m-p/3200131) helps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.